# What are the synonymous words of material(as a person with a specified quality or suitability)

Tags: word-request

I always have this awkward moment, I saw one example sentence on online dictionary and I forgot the word, the sentence was about: I'm not the good material for that. Thus I'm asking is there anything word means the same as Material in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

> Girl A: Look at Chad Wilson, He's so cute
>   Girl B: I know, He's **not husband material** though

The expression in bold means that he is not suitable to get married to- perhaps because he's unfaithful, a womanizer or unemployed. He would not make a good husband!

We use **[something] material** to say someone is suitable for something, or the negative form to suggest that they are not suitable for a particular thing, position or job. More examples:

> They are definitely going to promote Wilson to regional manager: he is management material. -*he is suitable/a good fit to become a manager*

Comment: **manager material** is not idiomatic: the normal expression is **management material**. See this NGram graph: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+manager+material%2C+is+management+material&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20management%20material%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks for editing the answer. with much respect, I do insist that it's idiomatic, I've checked it in the COCA before posting my answer. Also, https://ludwig.guru/s/manager+material - I'm not saying management material is incorrect, heck it even sounds better :) however based on the 'research' I did "manager material" is also possible. You still think it is not?

Comment: Mmmmm... looking at the link that you quoted, it only found four exact matches for **manager material**, compared to fifteen for **management material**. Of those, two were "trainee manager material" and "'home manager' material". These compound nouns have a different meaning. That's why I put "**is** manager" in my NGRAM search. Another is from David Beckham, who is known for his unusual grammar http://www.stgeorges.co.uk/blog/english-grammar-david-beckham-style . The remaining quote is from an article that contains two punctuation errors in the first paragraph- not a good omen.

Comment: @javalatte yeah you're right management is much more common. Thanks :)

Comment: Please note that "uncommon" is *not* the same thing as "not idiomatic".  "manager material" is used less commonly but is still perfectly idiomatic (meaning most people would not think it "sounds strange" if they heard it).